# Flutter : How to make every card unique using Listview.builder?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

**This is the code I have written in my home.dart file.**

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: 245,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount:10,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return VideoCard(long: true);
                      }
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

This is the VideoCard() class

```
class VideoCard extends material.StatelessWidget {
  final bool long;
  const VideoCard({
    @material.required this.long,
    material.Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  material.Widget build(material.BuildContext context) {
    return material.Padding(
      padding: const material.EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: CardWidget(
        gradient: false,
        button: true,
        width: long ? 360 : 180,
        child: material.Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: material.MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <material.Widget>[
            material.Container(
              width: long ? 360 : 180,
              height: 90,
              decoration: material.BoxDecoration(
                image: material.DecorationImage(
                    image: material.AssetImage('assets/images/bitcoin.png'),
                    fit: material.BoxFit.contain),
                borderRadius: material.BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: material.Radius.circular(10),
                  topRight: material.Radius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
              child: material.Text(""),
            ),
            material.Padding(
              padding: const material.EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: material.Text(
                "BITCOIN - A pioneer in Crypto!",
                overflow: material.TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 2,
                style: material.TextStyle(
                    color: material.Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'Red Hat Display',
                    backgroundColor: material.Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
            material.Padding(
              padding: const material.EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: material.Row(
                children: <material.Widget>[
                  material.Icon(BoxIcons.bx_bar_chart_alt_2, size: 16),
                  material.Text(
                    "Beginner",
                    style: material.TextStyle(
                        color: material.Color(0xFFADADAD),
                        fontFamily: 'Red Hat Display',
                        fontSize: 10),
                  ),
                  material.Spacer(),
                  material.Text(
                    "10 mins",
                    style: material.TextStyle(
                        color: material.Color(0xFFADADAD),
                        fontFamily: 'Red Hat Display',
                        fontSize: 10),
                  ),
                  material.Icon(BoxIcons.bx_timer, size: 16),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            material.Spacer(),
            material.Padding(
              padding: const material.EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
              child: material.GestureDetector(
                child: material.Container(
                  padding: material.EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 14, 0, 14),
                  decoration: material.BoxDecoration(gradient: Colors().waves),
                  child: material.Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: material.MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <material.Widget>[
                      material.Icon(BoxIcons.bx_play_circle,
                          color: material.Colors.black),
                      material.Text(
                        "Learn it",
                        style: material.TextStyle(
                            color: material.Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: 'Red Hat Display',
                            fontSize: 18),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  material.Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    CupertinoPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => VideoPage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the result I got.

[image]

But I want unique text,image for every card(list).
The dedign for every list should be same. But text,image,onTap() gesture should be different for every card(list) .
Is my logic is wrong?
Any answer is appreciated!

Comment: Rigth now, you just create 10 cards with same data. Are you have an parameters from server or local data that makes card unique?

Comment: @fartem  I want to create local data. So that the every card would become unique.I want to write data my own for each card.

Comment: Check answer below. But you can pass an entity that describes your data, not just text and image. Something like `CardData` (or other name, it depends on app specification). If in future your data will become more complex, all you need is a change data class, not constructor in widget. Also, Flutter provide Official Documentaion [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) with useful samples of `ListView` usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hard coded the text, image and onTap. You should pass the data from the map or list and use [index] to tell your code that card with index 0 in the list, should use text with index 0, and card with index 1, should use text with index 1.

If the items in your list will not change, and you want to hardcode them, you can do that without *.builder*. You can simply use **ListView** widget. You can also use Row and/or Column widgets.

```
ListView(
    child: Column(
      children[
       Card(),
       Card(),
       Card()
     ]))
```

If you want a two column design, create two Columns or ListView inside a Row widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to the constructor of VideoCard like `VideoCard(text: textFromListView, image: imageFromListView)`. In `VideoPage` you can do like this as well like `VideoPage(text: textFromVideoCard, imaeg: imageFromVideoCard);`

In VideoCard onTap() you can do like

```
onTap: () {
    material.Navigator.push(
    context,
    CupertinoPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => VideoPage(text: textFromVideoCard, image: imageFromVideoCard),
    ),
   );
},
```

Then in `VideoPage` you can access to text and image that you want to. Happy coding.

Comment: @SuryaGowda Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.